# jquery: how to use the .hide() methode with a .fadeToggle("fast") animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to use the same animation for `.hide()` which `.fadeToggle("fast")` is using.

when you see my code you see that i use a for loop to close open divs, and if i would use there a `.fadeToggle("fast")` it would open closed divs, so I am using `.hide()` but i want to same animation like `.fadeToggle("fast")`.

Can someone of you help me?

My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var anzinfos = 3;
    var x = 0;

    $('body').click(function (evt) {
        if (evt.target.id == "info")
            return;

        $(".div-info-" + x).hide("fast");
    });

    $(".info-btn").click(function (e) {
        if ($(this).attr('data') == x) {
            $('.div-info-' + x).fadeToggle("fast");
        } else {
            for (var i = 1; i <= anzinfos; i++) {
                $('.div-info-' + i).hide("fast");
            }

            x = $(this).attr('data');

            $('.div-info-' + x).fadeToggle("fast");
        }

    });
})
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What you are trying to do, can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your `HTML` ?

Comment: What you are trying to do, your `HTML` may help us to understand it, you are doing so many things in wrong way, i.e. loop is not required (IMO), try to describe your goal, make a fiddle if possible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Lcmwd/ --> i want to toggle the info divs if i click on an INFO-Button, and if i click somewhere else except an INFO-Button the div should close, an if i click on a other INFO-Button while an other info-div is open it should close.

i dont know why but my jquery isnt be usable in jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery provides three methods for doing fading.

[`fadeToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle) "toggles" the visibility of the element, so if it is shown it will be hidden, and vice versa.

There also exist [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [`fadeOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut), which do exactly the same animation as `fadeToggle`, but specify which way you want to go. If the element is already visible and you do `fadeIn`, nothing will happen.

You can specify the animation speed with these methods just as you can with `fadeToggle`

```
$('.div-info-' + i).fadeOut("fast");
```

Comment: thanks mate, and thanks for the explanation!

the reason why i didn't get it by the first answere was, that i had `.hide()` twice in my code and i only replaced 1.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery has a fadeOut() and fadeIn() methods.